# Endorsers Instantiate Chaincode with error "cannot find package"

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I created a chaincode and I imported a package to it.

```
import (
"bytes"
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"strings"
"golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer")
```

I can install that chaincode to all endorsers. But when I instantiated it to all endorsers, it faced the error:

```
endorser failed with error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "/chaincode/input/src/github.com/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go:85:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt (from $GOROOT)
/chaincode/input/src/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt (from $GOPATH)
/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

I tried to copy `golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt` package to the `/usr/local/go/src/` in the root directory, but it has the same error.

Comment: You have to `vendor` the `chaincode` directory. `vendor` means creating `go.mod and go.sum` files which contains the packages.

Comment: oh! it is really new to me. do you have a good source? I am sorry to disturb you!

Comment: In the `chaincode` directory, try `go mod init` command. it will create a two files `go.mod` and `go.sum`. then try `go mod vendor` command.

OR 

If you are using `dep` for dependency management then try `dep init`

Comment: @alpha I am sorry, now after i run go mod vendor, it produced go.sum. Thank you. Now, i run my code again, i will get back to you!

Comment: @alpha, It is still the same. Or i need to instantiate it using cmd? because i run my code using Java sdk.

Comment: check `vendor` directory is present or not in the `chaincode` directory. `go mod vendor` command creates this directory. 

Are you using docker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215729/discussion-between-alpha-and-dara-tith).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Installing the dependencies in the chaincode directory using below commands:

1. `go mod init` will create `go.mod` and `go.sum` files.
2. `go mod vendor` for creating a `vendor` directory.

Also if using `fabric:v2.X.X` then `shim` and `peer` packages moved to different libraries.
so change the `peer` and `shim` packages to below in the chaincode.go file.

1. `peer`  --> `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer`.
2. `shim`  --> `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim`

Make sure to add `peer`and `shim` changes before running `go mod init`command OR if you are already have a `vendor` directory then try `go mod tidy` and then `go mod vendor` commands to update the packages.