# Error: error getting chaincode bytes: listing deps for package chaincode_example02 failed: exit status 2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, peer, chaincode

After executing this command to generate chaincode(written in go) package:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode package  $CC_PACKAGE_FILE -p chaincode_example02 --label $CC_LABEL
```

where

`CC_LABEL=gocc.1.0-1.0`

`CC_PACKAGE_FILE=$HOME/packages/$CC_LABEL.tar.gz`

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: error getting chaincode bytes: listing deps for package chaincode_example02 failed: exit status 2
```

I am using Hyperledger Fabric version 2.1.

```
$ echo $GOAPTH
/home/divyas/Downloads/HF/gopath
```

```
$ cd $GOPATH
bin  pkg  src
```

`chaincode_example02` folder exists inside `src`

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor` inside your `chaincode` directory?
If the above solution didn't work then you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320288/endorsers-instantiate-chaincode-with-error-cannot-find-package/62321452#62321452) answer.